# Git - Uninstall & Install

Tags: powershell, git, windows-server-2008

I am new to Powershell and Git, I need some assistance / guidance on how to remove existing Git software from windows 2008 servers completely remotely (clean uninstall) and install latest version.

Also some steps / commands to validate that the un-installation and install was successful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: [You've asked this question before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74110597/git-uninstall-install). They gave you similar feedback. How was it installed? Uninstall it the same way. Uninstalling and reinstalling software is a normal course of business. Git is no different. There are plenty of docs/articles/blogs/Youtube videos on the uninstall/install topic (msi, GPO, PS, etc.). What have you searched for/tried?